# object expected in var errorMessage=" ";

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an error in the script which states that Line: 61
Error: Object expected.

Line 61 is var errorMessage="";

Can anyone show me waht the issue is and the solution?

Comment: You haven't given enough information.

Comment: can you post your full code and/or a fiddle

Comment: It might be something before the line that the compiler complain so please post more line of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sufficient information but just a wild guess:
make this line (61);

```
var errorMessage = new Error('some error message');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Good attempt! It works. But it now shows :new Error('some error message')
all the time.

Comment: <script>
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
var errorMessage=" new Error('some error message')";
event.preventDefault();
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|CF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
    }
if (!isValidEmailAddress($
("#email").val())) {
errorMessage="<br />Please enter a valid email address";
}

Comment: How to get rid of : new Error('some error message')?